Can someone help to convert an .nb file into a .pdf file without Mathematica?
I need help please in converting an NB file to a PDF so that I can open it.
I don't have access to Mathematica and Cloud version doesn't allow uploading files for free accounts.
I got it as a handout after attending a webinar.
File is uploaded on Wolfram here MEGA or Deposit too  or Fastupload
of course you can scan it with virustotal to ensure it's not a spam :)
Appreciate your support.
Update: I don't have Mathematica app, but will try now with Mathematica player
Update2: Mathematica player couldn't play on my laptop for security issue. Can someone help download my file and Save it?

Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Try: Wolfram Player.

Perhaps I am missing the point, but in File > Save As... there is the option to save a notebook as .pdf

I think the OP doesnt have mathematica

Mathematica notebooks are text files, and text files can be converted to PDF easily but you will not be able to understand most of it. Is your real question how write a Mathematica notebook parser? Or maybe you just want to recover the text in the notebook?

I already have it, but can't open it as I don't have the app. So wanted someone to export it for me
